# android-studio : not rendering shapes.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-studio

So, I created shape using shape.xml like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http//schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:shape="rectangle">
  <solid android:color="#ffffffff" />
  <size android:width="60dp"
        android:height="40dp" />
</shape>
```

But its not rendering the preview, in Preview pane.

I don't remember the last version on which it use to work properly.

Even, layout.xml 's preview is also not rendering when selected Android version is api22 : (Android 5.1.1).

I dont know why the last patch for update for 1.2 didn't actually fix this problem..

Any suggestions ??

Comment: Yes, there is a rendering issue from 5.1. Try 5.0.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't found the actual problem, why it was not showing in preview pane. I had to, finally, create a new project where this problem was gone, and copied files from my old project to this new one.

I must say, ANDROID STUDIO really needs some serious bug fixes, with some memory optimizations, as, not all configurations are capable to carry this heavy load on memory and CPU processing. Anyways, thanks to GOOGLE...